# Python Polars Group By and Indexing, for Time Series Data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-polars

I have been developing some codes in pandas, yet I found the executions in pandas are a bit too slow. I then stumbled upon polars, which claims to be blazingly fast and much faster than pandas. I have thus been trying to transfer my existing codes to polars.

I am currently working on some stock data, where I have to find out the minimum price of the previous n transaction days. Note that here the transaction dates are discontinuous, since there are Saturdays, Sundays and public holidays. The problem is that polars do not know how to find the previous transaction days, instead polars find the actual previous days.

Let's say now we have a DataFrame, and n = 3:

```
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Date       ┆ Price │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ 2     │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 3     │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 4     │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 5     │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 6     │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 7     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

The expected output should be:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
6    5.0
```

which I get from the following codes using pandas:

```
df.Price.rolling(3).min()
```

However, when using polars, since there are no indices, the group by function works differently. It sets the window based on the actual physical dates(continuous) instead of the transaction dates(discontinuous, pandas can handle that with indices), which yields the following results:

```
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Date       ┆ Price │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 3     │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 5     │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 5     │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 5     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

with the following code:

```
df.groupby_rolling("Date", period="3d").agg([pl.col("Price").min()])
```

Is there a way to get the desired result, i.e. same as the one in pandas, with the polars library? (Should I manually create an index column???) Or is switching over to polars a bad idea for data like this, since polar advocates for the idea of no indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dedicated `.rolling_*` functions, e.g. [`.rolling_min()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_min.html)

```
>>> df.select(pl.col("Price").rolling_min(3))
shape: (7, 1)
┌───────┐
│ Price │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ null  │
│ null  │
│ 1     │
│ 2     │
│ 3     │
│ 4     │
│ 5     │
└───────┘
```

You can also `groupby_rolling` on an integer column, where the period has a trailing `i` e.g. `3i`

```
(df.with_columns(idx = pl.arange(0, pl.count()))
   .groupby_rolling("idx", period="3i").agg(pl.col("Price").min()))
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ idx ┆ Price │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1     │
│ 1   ┆ 1     │
│ 2   ┆ 1     │
│ 3   ┆ 2     │
│ 4   ┆ 3     │
│ 5   ┆ 4     │
│ 6   ┆ 5     │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating a new column to store the index of the transaction day, and then using this index column to perform the rolling window operation:

```
data = {
    "Date": [
        "2023-01-01",
        "2023-01-02",
        "2023-01-03",
        "2023-01-05",
        "2023-01-10",
        "2023-01-11",
        "2023-01-12",
    ],
    "Price": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

n = 3
for i in range(1, n):
    shifted_price = df["Price"].shift(i)
    df = df.with_column(shifted_price.alias(f"shifted_price_{i}"))

min_columns = [pl.col(f"shifted_price_{i}") for i in range(1, n)] + [pl.col("Price")]
df = df.with_column(pl.min(min_columns).alias("min_prev_n_days"))

print(df.select(["Date", "min_prev_n_days"]))
```

Output:

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ min_prev_n_days │
│ ---        ┆ ---             │
│ str        ┆ i64             │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ 1               │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1               │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1               │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 2               │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 3               │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 4               │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 5               │
└────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. But I were to get some large values, e.g. 22 or 33. Would your method require a lot of overheads since polars will then need to create that amount of new columns?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it may not memory efficient

Comment: Is there a way to manually create an index then, so that I can use the groupby_rolling()?